# How to add nodes for parent/child in javascript html

Tags: javascript, html

Hi in the below code i have a tree view structure for building.In the tree view contains one building and different floors.
Now in that building i have 4 floors .suppose want to add another floor to the building .then how to do it.

then how to add child node to particular parent for the below code.once i click on add button then which i can able to add where it is under parent or child node

error:

```
morris.js:86 Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found
    at Area.Grid [as constructor] (morris.js:86)
    at Area.Line [as constructor] (morris.js:824)
    at new Area (morris.js:1451)
    at Object.Area (morris.js:1444)
    at dashboard-ecommerce.js:202
chartist.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at Object.c.createSvg (chartist.min.js:8)
    at f.e [as createChart] (chartist.min.js:9)
    at f.h (chartist.min.js:8)
chartist.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at Object.c.createSvg (chartist.min.js:8)
    at f.d [as createChart] (chartist.min.js:8)
    at f.h (chartist.min.js:8)
chartist.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at Object.c.createSvg (chartist.min.js:8)
    at f.d [as createChart] (chartist.min.js:8)
    at f.h (chartist.min.js:8)
index.html:222 Uncaught ReferenceError: wijmo is not defined
    at onload (index.html:222)
```

​

```html
    <div class="nav-left-sidebar sidebar-dark" style="margin-top:35px;">
                <div class="menu-list" >
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                        <a class="d-xl-none d-lg-none" href="#" >Building</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
                                <li class="nav-divider">
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item ">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#" onclick="myFunction()" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#submenu-1" aria-controls="submenu-1"><i class="fa fa-building" style="font-size:18px;color:gray"></i>Building</a>
                                    <div id="submenu-1" class="collapse submenu" style="">
                                        <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"  data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#submenu-1-2" aria-controls="submenu-1-2" ><i class="fa fa-building" style="font-size:18px;color:gray"></i>Floors</a>
                                                <div id="submenu-1-2" class="collapse submenu" style="">
                                                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#submenu-1-2-1" aria-controls="submenu-1-2-1"><i class="fa fa-building"  style="font-size:18px;color:gray"></i>Floor 1</a>
                                                               <div id="submenu-1-2-1" class="collapse submenu" style="">
                                                                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-product-checkout.html"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" style="font-size:18px;color:gray"></i>Conference</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" style="font-size:18px;color:gray"></i>Supervisors</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Coordinators</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Cubicles</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     </ul>
                                                             </div>
                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#submenu-1-2-2" aria-controls="submenu-1-2-2"><i class="fa fa-building" style="font-size:18px;color:gray"></i>Floor 2</a>
                                                               <div id="submenu-1-2-2" class="collapse submenu" style="">
                                                                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Conference</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Supervisors</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Coordinators</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Cubicles</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     </ul>
                                                             </div>
                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#submenu-1-2-3" aria-controls="submenu-1-2-2"><i class="fa fa-building" style="font-size:18px;color:gray"></i>Floor 3</a>
                                                               <div id="submenu-1-2-3" class="collapse submenu" style="">
                                                                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Conference</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Supervisors</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Coordinators</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Cubicles</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     </ul>
                                                             </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#submenu-1-2-4" aria-controls="submenu-1-2-4"><i class="fa fa-building" style="font-size:18px;color:gray"></i>Floor 4</a>
                                                               <div id="submenu-1-2-4" class="collapse submenu" style="">
                                                                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                                                        <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Conference</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Supervisors</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Coordinators</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>Cubicles</a>
                                                                        </li>
                     </ul>
                                                             </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                          
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>                       
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div id="theTree">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <p>
        Building:
        <input class="form-control" id="theInput" value="My New Node">
      </p>
      <p>
        Floors:
        <button id="btnFirst" class="btn btn-default">First Child</button>
        <button id="btnLast" class="btn btn-default">Last Child</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button id="btnNoSel" class="btn btn-default">Remove Selection</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Jyo, it is expected that you at least attempt this yourself and if you get stuck with a particular problem with your code, then ask a question here.  In it's current format, this is too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Comment: @Pete when we click on first child then want to add childnode first or last

Comment: Yes I get that but you need to attempt something yourself - otherwise this just looks like a do my code for me, in which case you need to hire someone, this is not the forum for that

Comment: @Pete just tried this link jsfiddle.net/Wijmo5/y4mgkhpf but without licence it is not working

Answer (score -1):

You can use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). Example:

```
var node = document.createElement("div");                // Create a <div> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Extra Floor");   // Create a text node
node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <div>
document.getElementById("building").appendChild(node);     // Append <div> to the building with id="building"
```